# Docusign session expire after signing

Tags: session, docusignapi

I am calling DocuSign API for generating document & once the document is signed, it says "The connection was reset."

I am expecting that it should not give "The connection was reset." message.
It should give some message.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kishor, it's possible to provide a better error message, but this is a security feature as the link to sign shouldn't be accessible by anyone. For remote signing the link allows anyone who posses it to click it and sign/see the document which is why it's protected and will expire in about 15 min.